# Remove all elements from each row of a csv that starts with a particular pattern in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a column in a csv which looks like this

```
Names
abc, ***ti***, sd
def, ***ui***
xyz, ***zi***, abc
```

From here I want to remove all elements that start with "***"

Expected output is:

```
Names
abc, sd
def
xyz, abc
```

How can I do this in Python

Attempts till now:

```
nrow=[]
with open("Documents/tes1.csv", 'r') as csvfile:  
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    itr = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        newstr = re.sub('\*', '', row)
        print(newstr)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Added my attempts till now. This is not working as it will only replace the '*' and not identify the particular string

Answer (score 0):

In your Python, `row` is a list of values from one row of the CSV file. You cannot pass this to `re.sub()`, you would need to pass each value one at a time to the function (possibly using a Python list comprehension).

If you only wish to remove all values starting with `***`, then Python's `startswith()` function would be faster (again, you need to pass the values one at a time, not the whole row at once).

```
import csv

with open("tes1.csv", 'r') as f_input, open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_output:  
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))  # copy the header
    csv_output.writerows([value for value in row if not value.startswith('***')] for row in csv_input)
```

The `writerows()` function could also do it all in one go. In effect it reads each row of values from the CSV one at a time, then discards any values that start with `***` and passes the resulting filtered lists to the `writerows()` function.

For your example input, this would give you `output.csv` containing:

```
Names
abc,sd
def
xyz,abc
```